# Comparision of number fractions

Tags: javascript

[Considering this topic in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)(and in other languages) can we guarantee that fractions that can be simplified to the same number will be always the same in JS? For example expressions like

`1/3 === 3/9; 3/9 === 6/18; 6/18 === 9/27; 9/27 === 27/81; // etc` should they always return `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes considering that you can't guarantee because there's a limit to the accuracy.
Example:

```js
var factor = 283763287462387;
var x = 15 / 7
var y = 15 * factor / 7 * factor;
console.log(x === y)
```